# Why does not argv work?

Tags: c++, c, compare, c-strings

I am a beginner to cpp and had a problem with the following code. Normally it should display the texts depending on the argv[1], but it does not display anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if(argv[1] == "a" && argc > 1)  printf("hello world, argc: %d\n", argc);
  else if(argv[1] == "2" && argc > 1) printf("hello everyone, argc: %d\n", argc);

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcmp` instead of `==`

Comment: @Andreas        Very quick one :)

Comment: As this is tagged C++, `(std::string(argv[1]) == "a")` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Roddy I am tempted to edit the tags, since there is no C++ code in the question (unless I missed something)

Comment: @Andreas - "I am a beginner to cpp"

Comment: You should first check that argc is more than 1 and then use argv[1]. As it is now your program is likely to break if the user doesn't input an argument

Comment: Hmmm, right - @www: do you intend to program `C` or `C++`?

Comment: There is an undefined behavior when running without arguments (out-of-range). Better to replace the condition statement with this: if (argc > 1 && ...)

Comment: You must check `argc > 1` in left size of `&&`

Comment: Actually I was planning to continue with cpp, but as you said c implementatin is OK too. Now I am trying the answers.

Comment: @www : C and C++ are very different languages. You need to pick which one you're using.

Comment: @Roddy. It is c++ then. I will remove C tag again. In the next steps I will need to convert anyway.

Comment: @Andreas Why do I get error when i use strcmp? I also included string.h?

Comment: @www we could either guess all the possible things you could have done wrong or you just tell us what the error is saying.

Comment: Whom should I pick for correct answer? Since this is relevant to c++ the first one or the second one (by Andreas) since it was my first thought as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `strcmp`, the following code should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "a") == 0) {
      printf("hello world, argc: %d\n", argc);
  } else if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "2") == 0)  {
      printf("hello everyone, argc: %d\n", argc);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Since the question is tagged `C++`, use something like the following to be more `C++`-like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if(argc > 1) {
      std::string argv1(argv[1]);

      if (argv1 == "a") {
          std::cout << "hello world, argc: " << argc << std::endl;
      } else if (argv1 == "2") {
          std::cout << "hello everyone, argc: " << argc << std::endl;
      }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
      std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not it is more clear :)

Comment: Ops. now it does not show the result even though I sent the argument "a" as input: `./helloWorld "a"` or `./helloWorld a` does not go in any of the branches.

Comment: Ops. Solved. I was trying to execute before `make` :)

Comment: +1, but you were quicker with `C++` solution ;-).

Answer (score 3):

2 most important issues with you code:

- You SHALL check number of arguments BEFORE arguments check.
- Strings are compared using standard library functions like `strcmp()`
  or even better `strncmp()` if you know maximum length.

Here is the **C code** that works. Hope this help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ((argc > 1) && ((strcmp(argv[1], "a") == 0)))
    {
        printf("hello world, argc: %d\n", argc);
    }
    else if ((argc > 1) && (strcmp(argv[1], "2") == 0))
    {
        printf("hello everyone, argc: %d\n", argc);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Some details aout string comparison. If you use `==` operator here (if you have not overloaded it) you just compare object addresses (look carefully, you have `char *` in both cases). Obviously your string literal and argument buffer have different addresses. You need to compare contents. Actually in C++ you can construct `std::string` and use comparison operator.

So another, **more C++ solution** that works based on `==` operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ((argc > 1) && (std::string(argv[1]) == "a"))
    {
        printf("hello world, argc: %d\n", argc);
    }
    else if ((argc > 1) && (std::string(argv[1]) == "2"))
    {
        printf("hello everyone, argc: %d\n", argc);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 - catched me by 18 seconds :)

Comment: @Andreas You still got the chance. It's tagged C++ not C ^^.

Comment: @a3f Done - see above :D

Comment: Hmm... I have read this too late :-).